# Extract Part of a text column using MYSQL

Tags: mysql

My DB Column contains the following text (CLOB):

```
Name
Abc corp
Type
Non profit
Main Address
123 Third Street
Cypress CA 90630
Secondary Address
987 Fifth Street
Cypress CA 90630
Date Formed
05/05/2018
Effective Date Formed
05/10/2018
Amendment Date Formed
10/01/2018
Amendment Effective Date
10/03/2018
```

In MYSQL i want to write a query that splits these

```
Name        Type                Main Address                        Secondary Address                   Date Formed             Effective Date Formed    
---------  ------------         ------------                        ---------------                     -------------           -----------
Abc corp     Non profit         123 Third Street Cypress CA 90630   987 Fifth Street Cypress CA 90630   05/05/2018              05/10/2018
```

Comment: For whoever decided to store the data this way in the first place: https://media.giphy.com/media/im8FmCX77BO0g/giphy.gif

Comment: True, but i have no control over that.. :( but I need these in separate columns to do some analysis

Comment: I can think of a solution in MySQL 8.x. Or do you have MySQL 5.x?

Comment: I have MYSQL 5.x